# Wipe per request prevents reloading of certain classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails wipes classes and reloads them if it detects file change while the server is running in development mode. I have the following structure:

```
app/models/algorithms/algorithms.rb (Module Algorithms)

app/models/algorithms/algorithm.rb (Base Class Algorithms::Algorithm)

app/models/algorithms/algorithm_a.rb (Extended Classes Algorithms::AlgorithmA)
app/models/algorithms/algorithm_b.rb (Extended Classes Algorithms::AlgorithmB)
app/models/algorithms/algorithm_c.rb (Extended Classes Algorithms::AlgorithmC)
```

These concrete algorithm classes are not instantiated by a controller, but in Sidekiq worker classes `app/workers`, which means normally not inside the Rails process, but inside the Sidekiq process.

Now, if I make a change to any file, for instance a controller, then Rails wipes the classes, and reloads them. This is great, but it does not reload the whole `app/models/algorithms` directory.

Why is that so? How can I configure this to eagerly load everything every time? I have set `config.eager_load` to `true`. The problem is not solved until I reference each class one after the other inside a pry session, then there are loaded again, one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation over at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html it seems you can add custom paths to eager load.

I quote:

> - config.eager_load when true, eager loads all registered config.eager_load_namespaces. This includes your application, engines, Rails frameworks and any other registered namespace.
> - config.eager_load_namespaces registers namespaces that are eager loaded when config.eager_load is true. All namespaces in the list must respond to the eager_load! method.

What I do find interesting though, is the following.

> - config.eager_load_paths accepts an array of paths from which Rails will eager load on boot if cache classes is enabled. Defaults to every folder in the app directory of the application.

To me, that would properly eager load your files as well.

I'd try adding the following to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.eager_load_paths += Rails.root.join('app/models/algorithms')
```

**Note:** This only works if `cache_classes` is set to `true`.

You can also eager load a namespace, this could be done by doing:

```
config.config.eager_load_namespaces += Algorithms
```

and then implement a method `eager_load!` that handles the setup properly.

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately the last advice does not work. I thought it would, because while `app/models` is in the list, `/algorithms` was not. Just a small remark, in `config/environments/development.rb` the `config.eager_load_paths` array is already frozen, I had to put it into `config/application.rb`

Comment: I see. And putting it in config/application.rb didn't solve it. Does `/algorithms` successfully being put in the eager load paths?

Comment: Yes, that works. I think the `eager_load_namespace` approach is promising, I add the `Algorithms` module and define a `eager_load!` method for it where I can make the proper setup. The question is, how can I define there to load the files in the `algorithms` directory? Just a `load` directive?

Comment: I see. Yeah a `load` should be sufficient.

Comment: Putting a `Dir[Rails.root.join('app/models/algorithms/*.rb')].each { |file| load file }` at the appropriate portion of the code fixes it. Kind of hacky, but for development I guess it's okay. Feel free to add this to your answer.